# Recursion or iteration for deleting certain files types within sub folders

Tags: c, search, recursion, iteration, delete-file

Would it be better to do delete certain file types within sub-folders recursively or iteratively?

### Recursion example:

- r = (if sub-folder open sub-folder, delete .bak files older than 1 week, if no sub-folder and if no .bak files older than 1 week print no .bak files older than 1 week found)
- Folder 1 (run r) > sub-folder 1 (run r) > sub-folder 2 (run r) > sub-folder n (run r) > the program deletes the 1 week old .bak files as it backs out of each folder.

### Iteration example:

- del = delete .bak files older than 1 week
- search = search for sub-folders, if sub-folders found put them into an array.
- Open = open each sub-folder one at a time, while in each sub-folder run del and then search again and repeat, until program reaches the last sub-folder there is within this branch.
- Move to next sub-folder branch from the root.
- error = if no sub-folder and if no .bak files older than 1 week print no .bak files older than 1 week found
- Folder 1 > del or error > search > open > move > print: # .bak files deleted in # seconds...

Comment: can you format and indent your pseudocode please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of iteration you need to maintain stack or queue manually (in case of DFS or BFS). If you not only want to remove the files but the directories also then DFS will be the best (as you can only remove empty directory). I think it is better to use the system stack to do the depth first search and at each directory, do what you want. The stack should not grow that much which causes a stackoverflow, unless your directory entries and the depth of directories are exceptionally long, which is less probable to occur.

Also you can set the stack size using `ulimit`.

Comment: I like the sound of DFS as well, but I do not wan to delete directories just .bak files older than 1 week found. what is the command for me to reference system stacks?

Comment: what do you mean by "reference" ?

Comment: I guess I mean could you give me some crumbs so I can start the code. I need a reference I can go by to see how stacks are coded in "C programming"

Comment: If you are using recursion you don't have to bother about the internal stack. You need to adjust size of the stack if your recursion is going deep enough and each instance is large enough to fill the present allowed. To adjust it check the `ulimit` command.

To code stack manually, just google for stack and you will get them everywhere.